# Kubuntu cannot copy file to external drive - errno: 5

Tags: kubuntu, external-hdd

Just until recently, I've been having trouble with transferring files from my laptop hdd to my external hdd as it keeps coming up with the same error. Is this because of my external hdd format not being ntfs? Is there a way to bypass this? I tried kdesuo - still doesn't work. Will a different file manager help? Any suggestions? Please and thank you.

Comment: What is the error? how are you transferring files? GUI or CLI?

Comment: @Maythux GUI. Pretty sure it's the ntfs fiasco. I did try formatting one of my thumbdrives to ntfs using windows, still the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issue, copying some large files From the NTFS HDD back to my system (ext4) HDD (home dir, ~/).
I put the files on the NTFS drive, why can't I copy them back?
It's Not All files.

I tried konqueror, krusader, terminal (knosole), console both as owner and root. Same error.

I tried copying the file to something simple eg temp.mp4. Same Error.
I tried renaming the file to a new name on the NTFS drive, as some 'Linux' utf8 characters or odd space chars mess with MS NTFS, especially if the file came from the internet in 'foreign language', but got error too.

******* **So, What I Did that Worked**. *******

I 'archived' (tar.gz) the file in place on the NTFS HDD then MOVED the archive to my ~/ drive and extracted it there and all was Good.

There must be a bit error in the file some where that cp does not like, but is not enough to keep the file from being view in an application.

ps. I was able to view, use the file from the NTFS external HDD, but just couldn't copy it.. I was afraid to 'Move' the file as I didn't want to 'lose' it permanently if something went wrong. Good chance it would, eh.

in short: Compress, Archive, Tar, Zip etc. Move. Then decompress, expand, extract etc.

Hope this helps. I know it's NOT a solution.. just a work around.

Landis.